# Powerbuilder resource file with spaces in icon names

Tags: icons, powerbuilder

I created a Powerbuilder app that uses picture buttons. Some icons have names with spaces in them ('icon 1.png'). Now I created a resource file (.pbr). Rebuild goes thrue without problems, however when I ran the app, the picture buttons with icons that have spaces in the title show a white image. It works fine for buttons without spaces ('icon2.png').

Is there a way to make a valid .pbr with spaces? I tryed editing icon paths with ",',~b but I get errors during rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use spaces in the icon file names. I am already using in Powerbuilder 11.5. What version do you use?

Comment: 12.5.2 build 5629 on Windows 7 pro 64

I could not get it to work, so I changed the icon names (eliminated spaces). Now it works fine.

Comment: Great! You made youself simple :)

Comment: Simple - yes. Time consuming - yes :D